# Kivy/Pyinstaller Mac app dock icon resolution issue

Tags: python, macos, kivy, pyinstaller

I have a kivy app that I'm bundling for mac through pyinstaller.

I've set the pyinstaller app icon in the spec file:

```
...
app = BUNDLE(exe,
             icon='resources/app_icon.icns',
...
```

And I've set the icon in kivy:

```
class ThreadedApp(App):
    ...
    self.icon = os.path.join(self.resource_path, 'resources/app_icon.ico')
```

When the app first boots, the high quality icon shows in the dock. This is replaced with the kivy icon as the bootloader does its thing.

The issue comes after the app is loaded, when I get a low quality version of the icon in the dock, almost like kivy converted it to a tiny version for the title bar, (like in windows), then used that for the dock icon.

Is there a fix for this? I've tried using a 1024x1024 image like the docs mention, but it still scales down to garbage quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by swapping the .ico to a .png.